# NSUncaughtExceptionHandler is not getting called on iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I use `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` to set the handler in my app delegate `didFinishLaunching`... method, then create a deliberate crash in my app code, but the `uncaughtExceptionHandler` never gets called: neither on simulator nor on device.

It used to work in this same code on the previous iOS versions.  But starting iOS 6 - not any more. Anyone has the same behavior?  I googled around, but haven't found any explanation.
Thank you for any responses.

Comment: Have you figured out what's going on? I have a similar issue...

Comment: Nope, I haven't.  We've integrated HockeyApp (QuincyKit) into the app - and it catches the exceptions now.

Comment: There is nothing like this should not work on iOS 6. In apple docs its said to be available from iOS 2.0 and later. Can you paste the code you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one `NSUncaughtExceptionHandler` app-wide. It's possible that some other code in your application is registering a handler (after you do), and thus that code catches the exceptions and you don't.